# Running a BASH script via crontab causes ecryptfs volume to unmount

Tags: debian, cron, ecryptfs

On my MX-18 linux (Debian 9 Stretch based) system, whenever a script runs via cron, my Private ecryptfs volume unmounts.

Confirmed, no issue running the same BASH scripts from a terminal. Tested with two different scripts. The crontab is set up with crontab -e from my standard user account.

Can't find anything on the web about this.

Cheers

Comment: I know Cron opens and closes a PAM session to perform tasks. This might trigger any .profile or .logout scripts you have. Might this be related?

Comment: You seem to be focusing on bash scripts. What happens if you run a simple command (like `date > /tmp/x` or `cp y z`) via cron?

Comment: I added * * * * * date > /tmp/datefile to crontab. This also causes my ecryptfs folder to unmount. So, it does seem to be cron, not the bash script.

Comment: Regarding PAM session, I don't know about that. I'll dig into it a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Running things in root crontab whilst logged in as a user (owner of the ecryptfs volume) doesn't cause the problem. This is a workaround for now. The replies led me to try this... thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of ecryptfs-utils, here is the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/259293

A workaround is to delete the following file:

```
rm ~/.ecryptfs/auto-umount
```